# Do the genes encoded by the nucleus for mitochondrial proteins have introns?

Tags: mitochondria, introns

Mitochondria are believed to have transferred much of their genome to the nucleus. I know that mitochondrial protein-coding genes lack introns, but is this true for mitochondrial genes encoded by the nucleus as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nuclear genes for proteins destined for the mitochondrion **can** have
>   introns…

…to the extent that other nuclear genes for that organism have introns.

For certain insects there is a database of such genes entitled [MitoDrome](http://mitodrome.ba.itb.cnr.it), and if you click on *D. melanogaster* in the side panel on the home page of that site you get to a list of such genes for the eponymous fruit fly. You can inspect each one with the ‘view’ option, and the first few I looked at all had introns. Here is an example for one of the subunits of NADH-ubiquinone oxidoreductase, [ND-18](http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0031021):

[image: Exon-intron structure of CG12203]

The subunits of this enzyme complex can be examined in other species, from which one can find that in *Homo sapiens* these nuclear genes also have introns. A related human gene is [NDUFS4](http://may2017.archive.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=ENSG00000164258;r=5:53560633-53683340). Mutations in this gene have been described, at least one of which results in a genetic desease — Leigh syndrome. One of these mutations involves abberant splicing of the five exons of the gene ([Lamont *et al.* Am J Med Genet Part A 173A:596–600](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ajmg.a.37983)).

The homologous gene in *Saccharomyces cerevisiae*, [NDI1](http://fungi.ensembl.org/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae_yjm789/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=SCY_4056;r=AAFW02000020:21630-23171;t=EDN64274), does not have introns, like most other yeast genes.